# Acumatica using In <> Operator in BQL for integer

Tags: operator-keyword, acumatica

We're trying to use `IN` operator on BQL to select multiple inventories, but it's not working. 
For example,

```
   int[] items = new int[] { 154, 184 };
   foreach (SOLine item in PXSelect<SOLine,Where<SOLine.inventoryID,In<Required<SOLine.inventoryID>>>>.Select(this, items))
    {

    }
```

I've also referred the blog below that illustrates using the IN operator for a string: 
https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2017/11/sql-in-operator-in-bql.html. We are trying for integer type in a similar way. I'm not sure what we're missing. It would be great if some one can help identify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acumatica ORM entity DB types are all nullable. You are using an array of non-nullable values 'int[]' instead of an array of nullable values 'int?[]'.

Code:

```
int?[] items = new int?[] { 154, 184 };

foreach (SOLine item in PXSelect<SOLine, 
                        Where<SOLine.inventoryID, 
                        In<Required<SOLine.inventoryID>>>>.Select(this, items))
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its working now based on your solution.